# how to make a shadow in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, shadow

I need to draw a canvas `rect` with shadow which has shadows on four sides of the `rect`, similar to a div has style as `"box-shadow":"0px 0px 5px 5px"`

Comment: Can you show us some code? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `context.shadowColor` plus `context.shadowBlur` to create the `box-shadow` effect.

Canvas's blur is very light so you must often overdraw the blurs to make them prominent.

Here's my version of your `box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px`:

[image]

Example annotated code:

```
shadowRect(10,10,105,45,5,'red');

function shadowRect(x,y,w,h,repeats,color){
    // set stroke & shadow to the same color
    ctx.strokeStyle=color;
    ctx.shadowColor=color;
    // set initial blur of 3px
    ctx.shadowBlur=3;
    // repeatedly overdraw the blur to make it prominent
    for(var i=0;i<repeats;i++){
        // increase the size of blur
        ctx.shadowBlur+=0.25;
        // stroke the rect (which also draws its shadow)
        ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
    // cancel shadowing by making the shadowColor transparent
    ctx.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    // restroke the interior of the rect for a more solid colored center
    ctx.lineWidth=2;
    ctx.strokeRect(x+2,y+2,w-4,h-4);

}
```

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

shadowRect(10,10,105,45,5,'red');

function shadowRect(x,y,w,h,repeats,color){
  // set stroke & shadow to the same color
  ctx.strokeStyle=color;
  ctx.shadowColor=color;
  // set initial blur of 3px
  ctx.shadowBlur=3;
  // repeatedly overdraw the blur to make it prominent
  for(var i=0;i<repeats;i++){
    // increase the size of blur
    ctx.shadowBlur+=0.25;
    // stroke the rect (which also draws its shadow)
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
  }
  // cancel shadowing by making the shadowColor transparent
  ctx.shadowColor='rgba(0,0,0,0)';
  // restroke the interior of the rect for a more solid colored center
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
  ctx.strokeRect(x+2,y+2,w-4,h-4);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px;}
```

```html
<h4>box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px red</h4>
<div style="box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px red; height: 40px; width:100px;"></div>
<br>
<h4>Canvas "box-shadow" using context shadowing</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=100></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.shadowColor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowColor) property in combination with [shadowBlur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowBlur), [shadowOffsetX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowOffsetX), or [shadowOffsetY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/shadowOffsetY) does just that.

Example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const shadowRect = ({
  x = 15,
  y = 15,
  w = 100,
  h = 40,
  fillStyle = 'tomato',
  shadowOffsetX = 0,
  shadowOffsetY = 3,
  shadowBlur = 15,
  shadowColor = "rgba(21, 24, 50, 0.3)"
} = {}) => {
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
  ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
  ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
  ctx.shadowColor = shadowColor;
  ctx.fillStyle = fillStyle;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}


shadowRect({ fillStyle: '#C99DFE' });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.shadowRect {
  margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
  background-color: #C99DFE;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(21, 24, 50, 0.3);
  border-radius: 2px;
  width:100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h4>CSS</h4>
<pre>
width: 100px;
height: 40px;
margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
background-color: #C99DFE;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px rgba(21, 24, 50, 0.3);
</pre>
<div class="shadowRect"></div>
<br>
<h4>Canvas</h4>
<pre>
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15;
ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(21, 24, 50, 0.3)';
ctx.fillStyle = '#C99DFE';
ctx.fillRect(15, 15, 100, 40);
</pre>
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=100></canvas>
```